# Twitter API bad request?

Tags: wordpress, twitter, widget, bad-request

I'm using 2 widgets on a WP page - 1 is built into the theme and uses the API and the other is the code copied directly from the twitter widgets page, neither is working, in fact, even on the twitter widgets page it's getting the same 400 bad request error: https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

Is this an issue with twitter that for some reason isn't showing up on http://status.twitter.com ?

Comment: I've had this before, and have found it just to be a bit of an unreliable service, can't be any more help though.

Comment: Yup. Seems to be intermittent. It's back on now... for now...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to simply be an issue with Twitter not being reliable. It's on/off all morning. Anyone having similar issues.... just wait it out, unfortunately.